# unable to import spark.implicit._ using Intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DF_Exple1 {
  val spark: SparkSession=SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("sparkpika").getOrCreate()
  val data2018 =spark.read.csv("D:\\bigData\\File\\Sales.csv")
  data2018.show()
}
```

I tried to `import spark.implicits`._ but it is getting hide automatically and unable to see run status.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it is getting hide automatically"_? What is _"it"_?

Comment: do you have auto import on? if so it may automatically remove unused imports

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define **main method** or extend the object using **App** trait which will act as entry point for execution

First Create **SparkSession** in the following way

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession    
object DF1_Ex extends App{
val Spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
            .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
            .getOrCreate()
```

Now import

```
import Spark.implicits._
```

**Spark** here refers to SparkSession which was already created above

Comment: Thanks Prasanna kumar extend the object using APP is perfectly working. Thanks everyone....

Comment: @Gajraj can you please mark it as correct answer and upvote it then.Thank you